# How to base64 images using webpack?

Tags: image, webpack, base64, webpack-5

I am using https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter for my project

I do have `svg` and `png` images that referenced in my html file like `<img src="/public/image.png"/>`

Instead of loading image using src path I want to inject image as base64 content to my html file to improve the page performance and to minify the number of server requests.

So I wonder how would you do that?

UPDATE:

here is what I did, but that does not work

```
npm install url-loader --save-dev
```

and add this configuration to [production config](https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/blob/main/webpack/webpack.config.prod.js):

```
  module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'url-loader',
                options: {
                  limit: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
         ]
       }
```

I tried to play with `limit` values but won't help.
Any ideas ?

UPDATE:

that is my current `rules` config, but nothing works, I also installed `html-loader` but no effect:

```
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css/i,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'postcss-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: false,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/i,
        loader: 'html-loader',
      },
    ],
```

Comment: How is your html file used?

Comment: @tmhao2005 it is just a normal html file that I open in the browser by serving that using local server or hosting it in the coloud

Comment: I meant how is your html built by webpack. Is that via HtmlWebpackPlugin plugin?

Comment: @tmhao2005 I am not really expert in webpack, here is the configs https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/tree/main/webpack

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to set `url-loader` litmit to `true`. According to [their docs](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader#limit), setting it to `true` is the default option and there's no limit to a file's size to be transformed into base64.

Setting it to `false` will **not** transform images to base64.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/i,
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: true,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ]
}
```

Also, in order for images to be handled by webpack, you need to import them.

`import MyImage from '../public/image.png'`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few steps you should follow to sort your problem out:

- Add `html-loader` to your `webpack.config.prod.js`:

`webpack.config.prod.js`

```json
{
  test: /\.html$/i,
  loader: 'html-loader',
},
```

- Fix your `src` of your `<img />` to use the relative path instead of absolute path which doesn't work:

```html
<img src="../public/image.png"/> // this is incorrect `/public/image.png`
```

- Finally, add a `publicPath` to `output` in `webpack.common.js` to make it work properly with `html-webpack-plugin`:

`webpack.common.js`

```json
{
  output: {
    // ...
    publicPath: '/',
  },
}
```

Comment: I am not really expert in webpack, here is the configs https://github.com/wbkd/webpack-starter/tree/main/webpack, so does your solution taking the existing config in to consideration?

Comment: As I already dropped you an answer, did you check that anyway?

Comment: yeah, please see my updated config, seems `html-loader` does not work

Comment: also I stick the `url-loader` options in to dev config to test it out and same effect there, does not work. I tried to play with the order but didn't help