# Different output for require() method after upgrading Vue Application

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, babel-loader

I've a Vue Application with `webpack` and old `babel` version. When I upgraded it to `vue-cli` and new `@babel`, it output unexpected result for images.

---

**Following Code results different output:**

```
require('./assets/logo.png')
```

**Old Application (Required) Output:**

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMgAAADICAYAAACtWK6eAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5c...
```

**New Update Output:**

```
/img/logo.82b9c7a5.png
```

I'm not sure, whether it is due to the `vue-cli` or `@babel` or any other dependencies. Please help me to figure out this problem.
I've pushed basic boilerplate for these 2 applications in Git.

- [App with Webpack](https://github.com/dipenchand/app-webpack.git)
- [Appp with Vue-Cli](https://github.com/dipenchand/app-vuecli.git)

Comment: It's caused by Webpack config, which is Vue CLI responsible for. The current behaviour is preferable because using data64 for big images is realy ineffective. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/67377358/3731501

Comment: @EstusFlask 
My images are smaller as 8KB, and I used it for thumbnails. Thank you for the links. But `html-loader` throws compilation error: `TypeError: this.getOptions is not a function`. Could you please edit my repos directly [app-vue-cli](https://github.com/dipenchand/app-vuecli.git)

Comment: Did you try the recommendation from the Vue-CLI documentation regarding `maxSize`? https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/html-and-static-assets.html#relative-path-imports

Comment: @IVOGELOV I've just tried. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vue CLI 4 uses [`url-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/) for image URLs (specifically for `*.png`,`*.jpg`,`*.jpeg`, `*.gif`, and `*.webp`). If an imported image is within a size limit, the image is inlined as a [data URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs). Otherwise, it's passed onto [`file-loader`](https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/), which returns the resolved path URL to the file.

Vue CLI uses a [fixed inline limit set at 4096 bytes](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/15b1e1b/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js#L19) for the `url-loader`. The [logo in your example is 6849 bytes](https://github.com/dipenchand/app-vuecli/blob/d38408d/src/assets/logo.png), which exceeds the inline limit, causing it be to loaded as a path URL.

You can change the inline limit with the following [Vue CLI config file](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js) (needs to be created in your case):

```js
// <projectRoot>/vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
      .use('url-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        options.limit = 8 * 1024 // 8KiB
        return options
      })
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Vue CLI 5 does not use `url-loader` and `file-loader`

You need to use this code:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
        .set('parser', {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: 8 * 1024 // 8KiB
          }
        })
  }
}
```

PS: set `maxSize` to `-1` if you want to store the files instead of their hashes